# C++ std::unique_ptr with STL container

Tags: c++11, stl, unique-ptr

I got a piece of code which uses a std::set to keep a bunch of pointer.

I used this to be sure of that each pointer will present only once in my container.

Then, I heard about std::unique_ptr that ensure the pointer will exists only once in my entire code, and that's exactly what I need.

So my question is quite simple, should I change my container type to std::vector ? Or It won't changes anything leaving a std::set ?

Comment: std::unique_ptr doesn't ensure that only one pointer points to a certain address.

Comment: Yes, but if I create my object with new std::unique_ptr< ... >(new ...()), or std::make_unique< ... >( ... ) ?

Comment: Should the container own the objects pointed to by the pointers? Do you even need pointers in the first place?

Comment: You are pretty safe when using make_unique. But you won't get total safety at any point. I.e. `auto x = new xyz(); auto a = unique_ptr(x), b = unique_ptr(x);` and don't use `new` to create a unique_ptr, you will lose the advantages smart pointers give you.

Comment: Timo, I'm ok with new xyz() example.

Comment: Caleth I'm starting to think about that ;)

Comment: Provide some code example, please. If you store pointer to object in set, then why not store object itself? Unique_ptr purpose is to pass "ownership" of object. So when the unique_ptr is destructed (i.e. element removed from set), then object will be destructed (guessing that's probably not what you want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the job your set is doing is probably different to unique_ptr.

Your set is likely recording some events, and ensuring that only 1 event is recorded for each object that triggers, using these terms very loosely.
An example might be tracing through a mesh and recording all the nodes that are passed through.
The objects themselves already exist and are owned elsewhere.

The purpose of unique_ptr is to ensure that there is only one owner for a dynamically allocated object, and ensure automatic destruction of the object. Your objects already have owners, they don't need new ones!